# How to change color of link buttons and link them to anchors in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, scroll, linkbutton

I want to create link buttons dynamically and link them to the anchors in a repeater.
Here is what I tried:

```
            int listItemIds = 1;
            List<CompanyModel1> companies1 = new List<CompanyModel1>();
            for (int ar = 0; ar < arrProcess.Length; ar++)
            {
                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.ID = "lnk" + listItemIds;
                lnk.Text = arrProcess[ar];
                lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;"); //This is to prevent the page to reload
                lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.colorClick); 
                lnk.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(ar); //LinkButton CommandArgument
                lnk.CommandName = Convert.ToString(ar); //LinkButton CommanName
                lnk.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command);//
                listItemIds++;
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lnk); // Adding the LinkButton in PlaceHolder
```

and

```
 protected void colorClick(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)o;
        lnk.Style["font-weight"] = "bold";

        //Process clicked link. for example jump to anchors
    }
```

In my aspx file, I created the place holder to populate the link button to:

```
 <div>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

I want to prevent the page from reload so that the result I binded to the repeater is still there. But I do not see the button links to change. I want to make it change in color and font style so that we know that it is clicked. More over I want it to jump to the anchors when clicked. But I don't know how to create that anchors. Do you have any idea on that ? Thank you!

Comment: did you try to use update panel

Comment: No I haven't. How is it so ?

Comment: check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Oh, I know this method. I created javascript function in aspx file, but I don't know how to get the link button ID from code behind file ?

Comment: I think its better if you can update question with HTML and how you add these created links to page

Comment: Yes. I updated my question and you can see how I created the link button in codebehind file and bind it to the place holder in ascx file.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove below line from your code it should work.

```
lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
```

If your page load have IsPostBack check that also need to remove.

Working Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] arrProcess = new[] { "link 1", "link 2", "link 3" };
        int listItemIds = 1;
        // List<CompanyModel1> companies1 = new List<CompanyModel1>();
        for (int ar = 0; ar < arrProcess.Length; ar++)
        {
            LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.ID = "lnk" + listItemIds;

            lnk.Text = arrProcess[ar];
            //lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "var btn = document.getElementById('"+lnk.ID+"');btn.innerHTML = 'Default Text';btn.innerHTML.style.fontWeight = 'bold';return false;"); //This is to prevent the page to reload
            lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.colorClick);
            lnk.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(ar); //LinkButton CommandArgument
            lnk.CommandName = Convert.ToString(ar); //LinkButton CommanName
            //lnk.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lnk_Command);
            listItemIds++;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lnk); // Adding the LinkButton in PlaceHolder
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }

    }



    protected void colorClick(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)o;
        lnk.Style["font-weight"] = "bold";

        //Process clicked link. for example jump to anchors
    }
```

**Update:**

You can stop full page post back using update panel like below. This will still call the page load but its partial call back.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Also master page you need to add a script manager.

Comment: I tried that, but the page still reload, even I removed the Ispostback. May be because it is on the content page, master page still have ispostback (cannot remove because it used to bind data). Is there any way to use it without reload the page ?

Comment: I added script manager at masterpage. Btw, what is the button 1 for ? Are all the button links still populated from code behind and bind to the PlaceHolder1? what is the difference here ?

Comment: button1 just for testing, no need that. Yes all the links are load from code behind. Update panel use to stop fully post back of the page. Its only updates that section only.

Comment: Sorry, I tried that but it still reload the whole pages. I don't know where the problem lying: is this because the master page and content page link together and master page also have page_reload, or because the code always load twice (I don't know why my code always load twice, I can see that when I run debug).

Answer (score 0):

You must use the **OnClientClick** event.
And the server to get it.

```
lnk.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick","window.open('Command.aspx','width=400,Height=400,top=200,left=200'); return false;");
```

This example opens a link. You can change its color.

> Update 1:To call with out reload page use this.

**jquery code:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "_Default.aspx/GetDate",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

**asp.net code :**

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried your method but it still reload when I click on it. Even I tried: lnk.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return false;"); it will still reload. Only "onClick" then when I click on link nothing happens. But I want click it change color and jump to the anchor.

Comment: Update: If I use lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "DisplayFunction(); return false;"); it will not reload on clicking. But if I use: lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "DisplayFunction(); return false;"); then I define DisplayFunction() in aspx file as: <script  runat="server">  
    protected void DisplayFunction(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {..} Then it will reload the page too.

Comment: onClick Event is server-side event.To run the server-side event asp.net will refresh your page.

Comment: Hi Hamix, I know u giving an example but could it be a little more close to my problem? I am trying to create button link or hyper links that it will scroll to certain part of the page (marked by anchors) when clicking.

Comment: For play with ui on client,You need Javascript or Jquery to use. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-Client-ID-Feature)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got what you want now. do the following steps.

We have to change your back end. I have use Hyper Link rather than Link button.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] arrProcess = new[] { "link 1", "link 2", "link 3" };
        int listItemIds = 1;
        // List<CompanyModel1> companies1 = new List<CompanyModel1>();
        for (int ar = 0; ar < arrProcess.Length; ar++)
        {
            HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
            lnk.ID = "lnk" + listItemIds;
            lnk.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            lnk.NavigateUrl = "#";
            lnk.Text = arrProcess[ar];
            lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "changeControlStyle('" + lnk.ClientID + "');"); //This is to prevent the page to reload
            listItemIds++;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lnk); // Adding the LinkButton in PlaceHolder
            //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }


    }
```

Then I have add a javascript method to page. that will use in the code behind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeControlStyle(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
</script>
<div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Comment: Are link.ClientIDMode and lnk.NavigateUrl legal usage? My compiler shows error for that, I using namespace system.web.ui, but they do not support that. My .net version may be 3.5. What are the equivalent declarations ?

Comment: HyperLink is a standard HTML. I am using .net version 4

Comment: If you use 3.5 ClientIDMode is not required (Not available in 3.5). NavigateUrl is required and its legal in 3.5. use the namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls also in your application

Comment: when I clicked on the links, it open the page: http://mywebsite/Myfolder/Subfolder/Companies/#, and the browser shows error: "403 forbidden: Access is denied". Before that I was in this link: http://mywebsite/MyFolder/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=2&tabid=15.

Comment: what you add to navigationURL

Comment: I use exactly what you put in your code: lnk.NavigateUrl = "#";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60522/discussion-between-seminda-and-user1314404).